# Mini Shell in C implementation of pipeline : wait for child process problem

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I've been trying to implement the pipeline functionality in a mini shell that I am building using C. However I noticed that when the pipeline contains processes that needs to wait other process and outputs to stderr not stdout , the effect is making the next commands in the pipeline also wait.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "variante.h"
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "readcmd.h"
#include <stdbool.h>


void execute_single_command(char **cmd){
   execvp(cmd[0],cmd);
}

void execute_pipeline(struct cmdline *l){     // *head_over=head // *head - > node 1
   int previous_pipe_read = -1;
   int file_descriptor[2];
   for(size_t i=0 ; l->seq[i] != 0; i++){
       pipe(file_descriptor);

       pid_t child_pid = fork();
       char**cmd = l->seq[i];
       

       if (child_pid == -1) {
           perror("fork error");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
       

       if(child_pid == 0){
           // Child process
           

           if (previous_pipe_read != -1)
           {
               // Redirect  to the reading side of the pipe ( file_descriptor[0] ) and use it as stdint
               dup2(previous_pipe_read, 0);
               close(previous_pipe_read);
           }

           if (l->seq[i + 1] != 0)
           {
               // Redirect stdout to the writing side of the pipe ( file_descriptor[1] )
               dup2(file_descriptor[1], 1);
           }
           // Close unecessary file descriptor
           close(file_descriptor[0]);
           // Execute command
           execute_single_command(cmd);
       }
       else{

           // Parent process
           // Handle the signal received by a terminated child process
           close(file_descriptor[1]); // Close unecessary file descriptor
           
           if (previous_pipe_read != -1)
           {
               close(previous_pipe_read);
           }

           
           if (!l->bg)
           {
               int status;
               waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);
           }


           // save the reading side of the pipe (aka the ouput of the previous command) into the variable previous_pipe_read
           previous_pipe_read = file_descriptor[0];
       }



   }


}



int main()
{
//  unrelated code

   while (1)
   {
       struct cmdline *l;
       char *line = 0;
       char *prompt = "ensishell>";

       /* Readline use some internal memory structure that
          can not be cleaned at the end of the program. Thus
          one memory leak per command seems unavoidable yet */
       line = readline(prompt);
       if (line == 0 || !strncmp(line, "exit", 4))
       {
           terminate(line);
       }

#if USE_GNU_READLINE == 1
       add_history(line);
#endif

#if USE_GUILE == 1
       /* The line is a scheme command */
       if (line[0] == '(')
       {
           char catchligne[strlen(line) + 256];
           sprintf(catchligne, "(catch #t (lambda () %s) (lambda (key . parameters) (display \"mauvaise expression/bug en scheme\n\")))", line);
           scm_eval_string(scm_from_locale_string(catchligne));
           free(line);
           continue;
       }
#endif

       /* parsecmd free line and set it up to 0 */
       l = parsecmd(&line);

       /* If input stream closed, normal termination */
       if (!l)
       {

           terminate(0);
       }

       if (l->err)
       {
           /* Syntax error, read another command */
           printf("error: %s\n", l->err);
           continue;
       }

       if (l->in)
           printf("in: %s\n", l->in);
       if (l->out)
           printf("out: %s\n", l->out);
       if (l->bg)
           printf("background (&)\n");

       /* Display each command of the pipe */
       execute_pipeline(l);
   }
}
```

For instance:

`sleep 5 | echo " Hello World"`

It will wait 5 seconds and then echo Hello World, Which is not the right thing. I am reflecting from a point where maybe I need to check if the previous command outputs to stdout to apply the pipeline effect.

Here is my code:

Comment: The shell launching the pipeline must start all the processes in the pipeline before waiting for any of them.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: If you have a pipeline `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`, the process(es) coordinating the execution must run `cmd1`, `cmd2` and `cmd3` (with appropriate plumbing — pipework — in place) before waiting.  In general, `cmd1` will produce too much output for the pipe to hold, and will not complete until `cmd2` reads its output, but if you're waiting for `cmd1` to complete before you run `cmd2`, you have a deadlock.  Similarly for all the processes in a pipeline.

Comment: Note that the first and last processes in a pipeline need special treatment compared with other processes in the pipeline.  Both commands in `cmd1 | cmd2` need special treatment, but the middle commands in a multi-process pipeline (`cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3`, `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4`, `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | … | cmdN`) get the same treatment: standard input comes from the pipe of the prior process, and standard output goes to the pipe of the next process.  That indicates why the first and last processes are different; there is no prior process for the first nor any next process for the last.

Comment: Once upon a long time ago, pipe sizes were usually 5 KiB; these days, they're usually 64 KiB.  It was relatively easy for test programs to fill a 5 KiB pipe, but it's harder to fill a 64 KiB pipe.  Your `sleep 5 |  echo "Hello World"` example is odd because `sleep` generates no output and `echo` doesn't read its standard input.